# pdf directly open in browser not saved using javascript?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013, ssrs-2012

I am using sharepoint 2013.I am hitting the ssrs api report directly download but i want to open in browser not download.How can i achieve this in javascript.
I am try with window.open() but not working and also try with "_blank".

Thanks.

Comment: Show us the parameters which you send via the SSRS API. The download is controlled by header elements sent by the server; there is nothing you can do on the client.

Comment: I am using rs:Format=PDF and rs:Command=render via the ssrs api.